# OpenGL Lighting and Material Error When Switching Between Different Scenes

Tags: opengl, lighting

I write a switch structure below to choose different scenes. For each case with a different scene, I enable something like lights, color material and depth test while I also disable them respectively in the end of this case. However, when switching between those scenes, something come wrong. Like, if I go to scene 3 first then go to scene 1, scene 1 seems affected by something extra from scene 3, such as unexpected light and material property would appear in scene 1.

Since I use different LIGHT in each scene, I don't think it's caused by lighting. However, I failed to see anything wrong in the material setting.

Could anyone give me some hint?

```
switch(m_iSceneNum)
{
case 1:
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, fNoLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, fLowLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, fBrightLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, fBrightLight);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glMateriali(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 128);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, fSpec);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, 1, 1, 4000);

    gluLookAt(0, 0 , 50.0f ,0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, fLightPos1);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, fLightDirection1);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, fLightCutoff1);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-10, 10, -10);
    glVertex3f(10, 10, -10);
    glVertex3f(10, -10, 10);
    glVertex3f(-10, -10, 10);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glFlush();
    break;
case 3:
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, fNoLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_AMBIENT, fLowLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_DIFFUSE, fBrightLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_SPECULAR, fBrightLight);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT3);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, fSpec);
    glMateriali(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 0);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, 1, 1, 4000);

    gluLookAt(0, 0, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_POSITION, fLightPos3);

    glRotatef(m_fAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, -1);
    glVertex3f(0, 5, 0);
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glNormal3f(1, 1 ,1);
    glVertex3f(5, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 1);
    glVertex3f(-5, 0, 0);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_LIGHT3);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glFlush();
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: How about you use some Modern OpenGL instead of all that deprecated stuff you're already using.

Comment: Longshot here, is GL_LIGHT1 enabled by default? I don't see it in the 2.1 specs. If so, tracing scene 3 after or before scene 1 might be different.

Comment: @Vallentin : Copy/pasting this comment on every OpenGL question is not really helpful.

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu Fun fact, I actually don't do that... Though living in the past and using old and deprecated code and technologies aren't productive at all. So if WE keep informing people which uses old technologies to update their knowledge about the technology they are using, then a lot of problems will disappear, and we can all follow along nicely and don't have to jump back and fourth all the time... Also fun fact, even though OpenGL "have" backward comparability, that isn't guaranteed at all. Which is the reason why some of the old things doesn't work on modern graphics cards.

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't know which part is not the Modern OpenGL, lighting or material?

Comment: @Jean-Simon Brochu I don't think GL_LIGHT1 would enable by default. And problem is the scene 3 would affect scene 1. However, even though I comment all the lighting and material part in scene 3, it still affect scene 1. How strange!

Comment: OK. I found where the problem is. However, I still don't know how to solve it. The problem is about normal vector. In scene 3, I set normal vector by myself. So it would affect scene 1. So I add glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL) into scene 1. The sad part is, it didn't work!! Anyone know what happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never provide normal(s) for the quad in `case 1`.

So you'll get the default normal (if `case 1` is the first/only thing executed) or the last normal you set in `case 3`.

It's as if you're assuming `glEnd()` resets the current normal to the default somehow.  It doesn't.

Comment: Thanks man. I found that. However, how to clear the current normal? I add glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL) in scene 1, it didn't work.

Comment: You can't clear it.  You *can* set it back to the default normal.  Check the GL spec for what that is.